# When I delete contact item (phone, email, etc), the item deletes but reappears

Tags: sync, gmail, people-app

In the People app, if I delete a portion of a contacts information (like their address or phone number) the information will disappear for a time, but the next time I view my contacts, the information is back. Plus, I noticed that no changes were made to the contact's information in gmail, but it should have been; the phone is set to sync automatically with my gmail account.

HTC DNA.

Comment: Hmm.. That is weird, the only things I can think of are: A service is running that syncs and updates your contacts (like HaxSync), or b) the time on the phone is not synchronized with Google's servers in a way that makes it think that the server versions are always the updated ones. I'm not too sure about (b) but it could be a possibility, can you Google "time <a major city close to you>"? and check that your phone's time is the same?